# How do I get King Zora to move?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

I played the whole game once before, and figured it out, but for the life of me I can't do it now.

How do I get King Zora to move?

Comment: First thought upon reading the title: You're only just playing this game *now*?

Comment: No, i played it through once before, and did everything except for get the ice arrow, killed ganon multiple times easily, but i couldn't remember how to get king zora to move.

Comment: I only got around to playing it a year or so ago on 3DS. DON'T JUDGE ME!  ::sob::

Comment: @immibis Some of us have never played it in any form. =p

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Show him Ruto's letter. It's in Lake Hylia (in a bottle) near the shortcut to Zora's domain.

Comment: mweep... mweep... mweep... mweep...

Comment: @Needpoule created an account just to show my appreciation for that comment

Comment: Oh my god, i just got that now. at first i though Needpoule was just being annoying, but i get it now. :P